# Google Script insert formula in 1 column where cell are black

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Hi could someone help me with this script im trying to insert a formula in all the blank cell from (J15) to (J38) here is what ive got but I just cant seem to get it the proper way any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
 function test() {

   var ssA = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();    //changed from openById() for my convenience
   var ss = ssA.getActiveSheet();          //change from getSheetByName() for my convenience
   var range = ss.getRange(15,10,24,1);    //row 2 column 7 (G) lastRow 1 column 
   var data = range.getValues();           //Gets all data
 for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++)         //this runs over entire selected range 
  {  
   if(!data[i][0])                 //If true then it's blank
   {
  data[i](('=Iferror(If(G15="",, if($B$5 = Iferror(query(\'Client 
    List\'!$A$2:$A, "select A where A =\'"&$B$5&"\'"),""),VLOOKUP($B$5,Client_Rate,2,False),VLOOKUP(D15,Config_Rate_List 
 ,2,False))),"")');)
    }
   }
   range.setFormula(data);   //Sets all data.  

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to put the formula to "J15:J38". If my understanding is correct, how about this modification?

I thought that it is possible that the cells of "J15:J38" have the values and formulas. So in this modified script, the formula is put to the empty cells which don't have both. The flow of script is as follows.

1. Retrieve values and formulas from "J15:J38".
2. Create range list.
3. Put the formula using `setFormula()`.

I think that there are several solutions for your situation. So please think of this as one of them.

#### Modified script :

```
function test() {
  var ssA = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();   //changed from openById() for my convenience
  var ss = ssA.getActiveSheet();          //change from getSheetByName() for my convenience
  var range = ss.getRange(15,10,24,1);    //row 2 column 7 (G) lastRow 1 column
  var data = range.getValues();           //Gets all data

  // The following script was modified.
  var formulas = range.getFormulas();
  var rangeList = [];
  var offset = 15;
  for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
    if(!data[i][0] && !formulas[i][0]) {
      rangeList.push("J" + (offset + i));
    }
  }
  var formula = '=Iferror(If(G15="",, if($B$5 = Iferror(query(\'Client List\'!$A$2:$A, "select A where A =\'"&$B$5&"\'"),""),VLOOKUP($B$5,Client_Rate,2,False),VLOOKUP(D15,Config_Rate_List,2,False))),"")';
  ss.getRangeList(rangeList).setFormula(formula);
}
```

#### Note :

- I was not sure whether the sheet name is `Client List` or `ClientList`, because of the line break in your script.
- I'm not sure about the formula which was put to cells.
- About your title, "black" of "Google Script insert formula in 1 column where cell are black" is "blank"?

#### Reference :

- [getRangeList(a1Notations)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getRangeList(String))

If this was not what you want, I'm sorry.

### Edit :

Unfortunately, the formulas in an array cannot be put the cells using the range list yet. I think that Sheets API can put various formulas once. But as a simple way, here, I would like to propose the following script.

```
function test() {
  var ssA = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();    //changed from openById() for my convenience
  var ss = ssA.getActiveSheet();          //change from getSheetByName() for my convenience
  var range = ss.getRange(15,10,24,1);    //row 2 column 7 (G) lastRow 1 column
  var data = range.getValues();           //Gets all data

  // The following script was modified.
  var formulas = range.getFormulas();
  var val = [];
  var offset = 15;
  for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++) {  
    if(!data[i][0] && !formulas[i][0]) {
      ss.getRange("J" + (offset + i)).setFormula('=Iferror(If(G' + (offset + i) + '="",, if($B$5 = Iferror(query(\'Client List\'!$A$2:$A, "select A where A =\'"&$B$5&"\'"),""),VLOOKUP($B$5,Client_Rate,2,False),VLOOKUP(D' + (offset + i) + ',Config_Rate_List,2,False))),"")');
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: That is exactly what i needed works perfect thank you very much

Comment: @Yvan Leduc I'm really sorry for my incomplete answer. I updated my answer. Could you please confirm it? And also, could you please update your question? You posted your question as an answer. In this case, users cannot answer to your answer. After you updated your question, please delete the answer you posted.

Comment: Thank you for helping me with this script it now seem to be ignoring the existing value and inserting the formula in all the cell from J15 to J38

Comment: @Yvan Leduc I'm sorry for the inconvenience. In my environment, I confirmed that the modified script works fine again. So could you please confirm it again? If it didn't work, can you provide your sample spreadsheet and latest script? I would like to directly confirm your situation.

Comment: Sorry Tanaike you are right your script work perfect I dont know when i tried it the first time something wasn't right i had formula in all the cell but tried it again and all is good sorry for the trouble and thank you very much for all the help

Comment: @Yvan Leduc I'm really sorry for my poor skill. Can you provide your sample spreadsheet and latest script? I would like to directly confirm your situation and solve your issue. Can you do this?

Comment: Don't be sorry your skill are much better then mine as I mentioned your script works good the way it is thanks

Comment: @Yvan Leduc Thank you. If you have any problem yet, feel free to tell me. I would like to solve your issue.